# Shiny Module for bslib::card -- where can I specify the id?

Tags: r, shiny, bslib

I would like to build a shiny module whose UI part is a card from bslib. Like

```
my_mod_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- shiny::NS(id)
    bslib::card(
        full_screen = TRUE, 
        bslib::card_header("My Title"), 
        bslib::layout_sidebar(
            sidebar = bslib::sidebar(
                open=TRUE,
                "Sidebar"
            ), 
            "Main contents"
        )
    )
}
```

Now the question I have is: **where does the `id` argument go?** There seems no named parameter in `bslib::card()` for this.

The background is that I want two cards with the same (but customizable) structure side-by-side in my dashboard. I think that a module would be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help documents of `bslib::card`

> ...       Unnamed arguments can be any valid child of an htmltools tag (which includes card items such as card_body(). **Named arguments become HTML attributes on returned UI element**.

Which means just pass an `id` argument

```
bslib::card(
  id = "myId",
  ...other arguments...
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not make the connection...